# Cannot connect Databricks with Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-blob-storage

I successfully mounted Azure blob storage using SAS key with below code

```
dbutils.fs.mount(  source = "wasbs://"+user+"@"+account+".blob.core.windows.net",
mount_point = "/mnt/"+mountName, 
extra_configs = {"fs.azure.sas."+user+"."+account+".blob.core.windows.net":key})
```

However, I cannot save output to the blob or display the blob directory (which it was worked before) 
Here are some part of an error 
"shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details."

"Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this resource type.
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:89)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:305)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:178)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:109)"

Does anyone know cause of this issue?

Comment: Does "user" match an existing container on the "account" storage ?
It is also possible that your SAS has expired.

Comment: @Alex R. Thanks much! it seem that my SAS is expired. 'Se' parameter is out of date.

FYI for all, here is detail of parameter in SAS key.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas